# Mixing multiple authentication model for same API is a best practice?

Tags: web-services, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

Sample API:

```
/product/list
/product/save
/product/update
/product/delete
```

Assume that `/product` is the base path that has a filter to verify the authentication before serving the requests.

At present, the OAuth authentication is implemented so all the requests are served after validating the access token. We got use case of serving one only context i.e `/product/list` in both OAuth authentication mode and **BASIC** authentication mode. But seems like mixing the multiple authentications for the same context is not a correct approach so expecting what is the best practice to be followed in this kind of cases

Comment: Show your Spring Security configruation.

Answer (score 1):

A good goal to aim for is a unified approach in the API, which always receives OAuth 2.0 access tokens:

- UI clients of the API get an access token via Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- Other clients such as back end processes get a token via Client Credentials flow

I would  get any clients using Basic OAuth to update to Client Credentials, which is almost the same, requiring a Caller Id and Caller Secret.

Both types of client will be able to call the list endpoint, and in both cases your API will need to validate the access token, identify the caller if needed, then possibly filter on which items the caller is allowed to get.